# How isFile() function from fs.Stats class works?

Tags: node.js

There are no details about `isFile()` function in [documentation of fs.Stats class](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

How it works? What exactly it checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the OS level an entry for a given entry is marked as either a file or a directory entry.  That information does not appear to be directly surfaced in the `fs.Stats` data structure, but it is something that the `isFile()` method can tell from the `fs.Stats` data structure.

By looking at the [code for fs.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L174) in node.js, you can see these:

```
fs.Stats.prototype._checkModeProperty = function(property) {
  return ((this.mode & constants.S_IFMT) === property);
};

fs.Stats.prototype.isFile = function() {
  return this._checkModeProperty(constants.S_IFREG);
};
```

Which shows that the information is contained within the `mode` property of the `fs.Stats` data structure.